# Python - Image stitching and blending

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, image-stitching

How can I blend little pieces of two images together?

What I'm doing is stitching two images together that have some overlap. I have the code to stitch images together with a given offset, I just need to smooth it out and make it look like one nice picture.
From what I understand, PIL blend only works if they're of the same dimensions and I feel like there should be an easy way to do this.

Answer (score -1):

There's code in OpenCV to do this but using C++ .. there's also a command line app that you could just call from your Python code.

[OpenCV stitching](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/opencv_stitching)